# Cannot loop simple array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have done this many time before but I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. I just need to loop this simple array:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset myData = deserializeJSON(getHttpRequestData().content) />

<cfdump var="#myData#" />
  <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(myData)#" index="i">
   Type #i#: #myData[i]#<br>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

But I'm getting this error:
[image]

Why can't I access the array with index key. Please somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like Dan said, you can't reference a struct object like that. However, that's also the wrong kind of loop to use for an array. Use an array loop. Or even better, use cfscript and a for/in loop. Or even better than that, use cfscript and a closure.

Comment: It's also a good idea to do a search on any error messages first. The error "Complex object types cannot be converted..." is pretty common and should've turned up a bunch of threads explaining why it happens and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable `myData` appears to be an array of structures.  That means `myData[i]` is a structure, and you can't simply output it.

You have to do something else.  What that something else is depends on your overall objective.

Comment: Thanks. I need to change my object structure.

Comment: @sg552 You can also cfdump your object to see what it is. That really helps when you're trying to figure out how to process it. If you see something more than a simple string in the row of your array, you're probably working with another object that you'll have to handle.